# NUXEO Attach Multiple Files on Single Document

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, nuxeo

I am newer to Nuxeo. I had integrated my Portal with Nuxeo 8.1 CE & now using Java Automation Client API I am performing Operations in Nuxeo from my Portal. My problem is I want to attach Multiple Files on Single Document. I found its operation as **BlobHolder.Attach** from http://explorer.nuxeo.com/nuxeo/site/distribution/Nuxeo%20DM-5.5/listOperations

But I am not able to find any such example of this Operation. Any example of this Operation will be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.nuxeo.com/blog/qa-friday-add-extra-files-document-content-automation/

Here is documentation for setting few blobs to document.
I`m not sure but you can try to set Blobs on chain call like in example below.

```
HttpAutomationClient client = new HttpAutomationClient("http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/site/automation");
Session session = client.getSession("Administrator", "Administrator");
File dummyFile = new File("/tmp/dummy");
session.newRequest("Blob.AttachOnDocument")
    .set("document", "/path/to/my/doc")
    .set("xpath", "files:files")
    .setInput(new Blobs(Arrays.asList(
            new FileBlob(dummyFile),
            new FileBlob(dummyFile),
            new FileBlob(dummyFile)
    ))).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am attaching the Implementation Method :

```
    String attachmentPath = null;
    if (!ioFiles.isEmpty()) {
        Session adminSession = NuxeoUtil.getNuxeoAdminSession();
        Document collectionDoc = null;
        try {
            collectionDoc = (Document) adminSession.newRequest(DocumentService.FetchDocument)
                    .set(NuxeoConstants.NUXEO_VALUE, originalCollectionId).execute();
            DocumentService rs = adminSession.getAdapter(DocumentService.class);
            DocRef docRef = new DocRef(originalCollectionId);
            attachmentPath = collectionDoc.getPath();
            if (docRef != null) {
                for (File file : ioFiles) {
                    Blob blob = new FileBlob(file);
                    rs.setBlob(docRef, blob, "files:files");
                }
            }
            NuxeoUtil.closeNuxeoSession(adminSession);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            _log.error(e);
        }
    }
```